Debian 12 fails to install over Ventoy 97?
I have installed latest ventoy-1.0.97-livecd.iso on my disk, and have put debian-12.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso in it, and after selecting locale and layout, it complains it can not détect installation media.
Old Ventoy around 63 used to be able to boot properly debian-live-11.1.0-amd64-standard+nonfree.iso . Even if this phrasing is not 100% correct, I would say this is a regression bug.
Any solution ?
My purpose is to start some net-inst CD. Legacy debian lack WiFi after first install.

ventoy is essentially a bootloader that would  boot an ISO you put into a drive - you use an installer to set up ventoy to a bootable USB, then boot into ventoy, which gives you a bootscreen to load the ISOs on it. If its an actual bug though, might be worth reporting to the Ventoy devs as its closed source

which boot mode do you chose when booting the Debian ISO from Ventoy?

Journeyman , saying it works fine with debian 11 implies -1- i know how to use Ventoy (and I don't use it the way you explain, and this is NOT the issue), -2- debian version is the only difference between my two attempts.
Golimar : bug happens both in normal and Grub modes. Mode does affect other issues, but not the media detection one.
